# Tensor shape while defining a tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensor

I am working on neural networks and many times faced problems with shapes.....Tensorflow provides us a keyword None so that we don't have to worry about the size of the tensor.....
Is there any disadvantage of using None in place of known numeric value for shape.

## method 1

```
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,None])
```

## method 2

```
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[64,100])
```

Will it make any difference while running the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow's `tf.placeholder()` tensors do not require a fixed shape to be passed to them. This allows you to pass different shapes in later `tf.Session.run(`) call. 
So your code will work just fine. 
It doesn't have any disadvantage because when we create a placeholder, Tensorflow doesn't allocate any memory. When you feed the placeholder, in the call to `tf.Session.run()`, TensorFlow will allocate appropriately sized memory for the input tensors.

If you use these `input_placeholder` in some operation in your code further, defining them with `None` i.e. an unconstrained shape, can cause Tensorflow to perform some checks, related to the shape of the tensors, while performing those ops dynamically during the `Session.run()` call. This is because while building the graph Tensorflow doesn't know about the exact shape of your input.